# Moshi: Getting Null values to pass through Retrofit 2 from an API Response

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, android-room, moshi

The API I am calling has a response that looks like this...

```
 [
        {
        "id": 755, 
        "listId": 2, 
        "name": ""
        },
        {
        "id": 203, 
        "listId": 2, 
        "name": ""
        },
        {
        "id": 684, 
        "listId": 1, 
        "name": "Item 684"
        },
        {
        "id": 276, 
        "listId": 1, 
        "name": "Item 276"
        },
        {
        "id": 736, 
        "listId": 3, 
        "name": null
        },
        {
        "id": 926, 
        "listId": 4, 
        "name": null
        }
    
    ]
```

There are null values inside the response, but I can't get the API call to work because of it. I tried having the 'name' field be to accept a null value, but I got an error. I heard that Moshi (the converter I am using) could have a way to serialize nulls, so that they pass, but not sure how to go about it.

Here is some more code for a better understanding

Network File

```
interface InfoCollections {
    @GET(ENDPOINT)
    suspend fun getInfoService(): Response<List<GetInfoJsonResponse>>
}

object NetworkingObject {
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().addLast(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
    val retrofit: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .build()

    val networkingService: InfoCollections by lazy {
        retrofit.create(InfoCollections::class.java)
    }

    val apiClient = ApiClient(networkingService)
```

The Repository

```
class InfoRepository(private val infoDao: InfoDao) {
    private val allInfoFeeds: LiveData<List<GetInfoJsonResponse>> = infoDao.getAllInfo()
    private val _infoFeeds: MediatorLiveData<List<GetInfoJsonResponse>> = MediatorLiveData()
    val feeds: LiveData<List<GetInfoJsonResponse>>
        get() = _infoFeeds

    init {
        _infoFeeds.addSource(allInfoFeeds){
            _infoFeeds.value = it
        }
    }


    suspend fun fetchInfo(): List<GetInfoJsonResponse>? {
      val request = NetworkingObject.apiClient.fetchInfoJsonResponse()
        if(request.isSuccessful){
            infoDao.insertAll(*request.body()!!.toTypedArray())
            return request.body()
        }
        return null
    }

}
```

The DAO

```
@Dao
interface InfoDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM info_response")
    fun getAllInfo(): LiveData<List<GetInfoJsonResponse>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertAll(vararg info: GetInfoJsonResponse)
}
```

The Data Class

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "info_response")
data class GetInfoJsonResponse(
    @PrimaryKey
    val id: Int,
    val listId: Int,
    val name: String
): Parcelable
```

Here is the error message
[image]

Appreciate the help guys, thank you.

Comment: Add your `GetInfoJsonResponse` class.

Comment: provide your error log also.

Comment: It's edited now.